# Error creating entityManagerFactory.Unable building Hibernate SessionF.SchemaManagementException:Export identifier[new_user]encountered more than once

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

My controller class -

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.erecruitment.app.repository.InterviewerDetail;
import com.erecruitment.app.repository.usernameExists;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class ClsInterviewerDetails {
    @Autowired
    InterviewerDetail intDet;
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @GetMapping("/interviewerDetail")
    public int interviewerDetail() {
        return intDet.interviewerDet();
    }
}
```

My JpaRepository extended interface -

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.erecruitment.app.model.ClsNew_User;
import com.erecruitment.app.model.user;
@Repository
public interface InterviewerDetail extends JpaRepository<ClsNew_User, String>{      
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value="SELECT 
    users_id,first_name,last_name,role,select_technical_skill,additional_skills FROM new_user 
    WHERE role='Hr Interviewer' OR role='technical Interviewer'",nativeQuery=true)
    int interviewerDet();   
}
```

My Pojo class -

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="new_user")
public class ClsNew_User {  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int users_id;       
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String first_name;      
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String last_name;   
    @Column(name="role")
    private String role;    
    @Column(name="select_technical_skill")
    private String select_technical_skill;  
    @Column(name="additional_skills")
    private String additional_skills;
    public int getUsers_id() {
        return users_id;
    }
    public void setUsers_id(int users_id) {
        this.users_id = users_id;
    }
    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }
    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }
    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }
    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    public String getSelect_technical_skill() {
        return select_technical_skill;
    }
    public void setSelect_technical_skill(String select_technical_skill) {
        this.select_technical_skill = select_technical_skill;
    }
    public String getAdditional_skills() {
        return additional_skills;
    }
    public void setAdditional_skills(String additional_skills) {
        this.additional_skills = additional_skills;
    }   
}
```

And , the errors which it is giving is -

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Export identifier [new_user] encountered more than once
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at com.erecruitment.app.ErecruitmentApplication.main(ErecruitmentApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Export identifier [new_user] encountered more than once
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Export identifier [new_user] encountered more than once
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.checkExportIdentifier(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:490) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
... 20 common frames omitted

How can I resolve these errors and exceptions ?

Comment: Take a look on how many @Entity uses @Table(name="new_user")

Comment: Yes there was two entities using same table name . Error is resolved , thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error cause of `Export identifier [X] encountered more than once` could be different.

You should check that your identifier 'X', in your case 'new_user' is not used more than once; for example: same table table 'new_user', table 'new_user' and sequence name 'new_user', etc...

As stated in the comment, your cause was two entiteis with the same table name.